# Tag accounts with highest rank in DAX

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have the following table in PowerPivot. I'd like to create a column ("Show") that will have the name of the quarter corresponding to the highest rank for all rows with the same ID. The table below shows the desired end state where "Show" is the calculated column I'm after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called 'DimShow', the following DAX should do the trick:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'DimShow'[Quarter],
    'DimShow'[ID], 'DimShow'[ID],
    'DimShow'[Rank],
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('DimShow'[Rank]), 
        ALLEXCEPT('DimShow', 'DimShow'[ID])
    )
)
```

**Explanation:**
We want to lookup a value from the [Quarter] column that has the same [ID] as the current row. At the same time, the [Rank] value should be the minimum value for all rows that has the same [ID] as the current row.

Note that this will produce an error, if there are more than one distinct value of [Quarter] for the same (lowest) rank, within a specific [ID].

Comment: Thanks! So under the hood the first look up value returns the filtered table of preliminary results, and the second lookup value is searched in that filtered table (and that's why we need ALLEXCEPT to retain that filter? Pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a variable to do this:

```
Show = 
    VAR TopRank = CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Rank]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[ID]))
    RETURN CALCULATE(
               MAX(Table1[Quarter]),
               ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[ID]),
               Table1[Rank] = TopRank)
```

The `TopRank` variable calculates what the highest rank is for that `ID`. The second line essentially looks up what the `Quarter` value is for that rank and that `ID`.